# Timestamps in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In order to take the Timestamps in javascript yuo can write this kind of code:

```
// Usual Way
var d = new Date();
timestamp = d.getTime();
```

But I found that is it also possible to get the same result in this way:

```
// The shortest Way
timestamp = +new Date();
```

Can someone help me to understand how the Shortest Way works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29).  It attempts to convert the argument that follows into a number if it isn't already a number.  The `Date` object implements a method that allows it to be converted to a number, which is the timestamp identical to the `getTime()` method.

---

A more legible and obvious way of getting a timestamp without using an extra variable is to use parentheses:

```
var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
```

Comment: ok, how the unary plus operator works is clear; for example +"1" gives me 1 as a Number; but why +new Date() gives me just the timestamps? I cannot see any timestamp string into Date {Tue Oct 04 2011 13:04:46 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)}

Comment: The timestamp is what is known as the "primitive value" of the Date object. The date is stored internally as the timestamp. When you try to convert an object to a number, the browser gives you that number.

Comment: Will it be possible to write a very basic example (an object with a primitive value) that gives the same result when I apply the + operator?

Comment: @AntonJs No, but you can do something [similar by defining the `valueOf` method](http://jsbin.com/owegek/edit#source).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a dynamic typed language, and it will try conversions appropriate to the context.

When adding a unary plus in front of the Date Object it will be converted to a number.